# Why isn't my object moving on MouseMoved?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

Simple question – why wouldn't an object move if it's the object of `.move()` inside `onMouseMoved()`? I'm trying to write Breakout as part of the Stanford 106A exercises on iTunes U and for some reason I can't get the paddle to track the mouse. I'm a java noob, so I'm sure it's something really simple. Could someone please take a look at this code?

```
/** Runs the Breakout program. */
    public void run() {
        setupBoard();
        addMouseListeners();
    }

    /** Provides the initial GCanvas and blocks for the game */
    private void setupBoard(){
        this.setSize(APPLICATION_WIDTH,APPLICATION_HEIGHT);
        addBricks();
        paddle = new GRect(PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
        add(paddle, WIDTH/2-PADDLE_WIDTH/2,HEIGHT-PADDLE_Y_OFFSET);

    }

    public void MouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        paddle.move(e.getX()-paddle.getX(), 0);
        }

    private GRect paddle;
}
```

I'm not sure if having `paddle` be an instance variable is appropriate in this case, since its "value" doesn't change (the paddle's always the paddle), but if I just define it as a new `GRect` within `setupBoard` I get an error in the `MouseMoved()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class that has the `mouseMoved()` method needs to implement the interface `MouseMotionListener`, and add the motion listener. Moreover, the event handler is `mouseMoved()` not `MouseMoved()`. So, e.g.:

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
    public void run() {
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        //...        
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {                  
        paddle.move(e.getX()-paddle.getX(), 0); 
    } 
    //...
};
```

Comment: You're right about the capitalization, but AFAIK addMouseListeners() adds both MouseListener and MouseMotionListener. I'll mark your answer correct if you'd like to edit. Can't believe I made such a stupid mistake.

Comment: @jefflovejapan - nothing to edit, addMouseListeners is a method in your custom (framework?) code that only you know :-) The answer is correct in all parts.